# Maximum formula: $\max\{x,y\}=\frac{1}{2} \left(x+y+|x-y|\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Show that:
$$ \max\{x,y\}=\frac{1}{2} \left(x+y+|x-y|\right)  $$

I have no idea how to prove this; most likely it is trivial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Geometrically, $\frac{x+y}{2}$ is the midpoint between $x$ and $y$, and $\frac{|x-y|}{2}$ is half the distance between $x$ and $y$.

So if you start at the midpoint and go half the distance in the positive direction, you end up at the right endpoint (or max).

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Harshal Gajjar: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm glad the answer made sense!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

If $y>x \implies |x-y|=y-x$ hence $\max\{x,y\}=y$.

If $x>y \implies |x-y|=x-y$ hence $\max\{x,y\}=x$.

For $x=y$, it's trivial

Comment: You could actually use only two cases; your first holds when $y\geq x$ and your second holds when $x\geq y$. The fact that the cases overlap isn't a problem.

Comment: thats true true if i consider the equality of x,y! but i didnt consider it in the first two cases! anyways thanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider two possibilities: $x<y$ or $x\ge y$.

Answer (score 3):

$\max(x, y)+\min(x, y) = x+y$ and $\max(x, y)-\min(x, y) = |x-y|$ thus $2\max(x, y) = x+y+|x-y|$. Therefore $\max(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+|x-y|).$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\geq y$ then $|x-y|=x-y$ and the RHS above becomes $\frac{2x}{2}=x$.
If $x\leq y$ then $|x-y|=y-x$ and the RHS above becomes $\frac{2y}{2}=y$.
In both cases it is $\operatorname{max}(x,y)$